# How to send user data like Id from post route to get route using redirect in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with a basic nodejs website which had a login, register, user routes. Initially the user register and redirected to login, And as he logs in the data is processed in /login post route then he is redirected to user /get route but how to identify the user that have logged in to show user data like profile. So iam stuck with how to identify the user who logged in and how to show his profile data in user /get route using render. As it was a redirect request data cannot be send through it.

I have tried using a undefined variable and using mongodb.

[image: User /get Route]

[image: Login /post Route]

Comment: add your code to the question [check how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please post code as text, not images.

Comment: That's what sessions are good for. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution for this is to create the session and check whether the user is available.

```js
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var post = req.body;
  if (post.user === 'user_name' && post.password === 'user_password') {
    req.session.user_id = 'user_id';
    res.redirect('/user');
  } else {
    res.send('Bad user/pass');
  }
});
```

You will get the user ID in /user using `req.session.user_id`.